# I want to connect a Drupal Docker-container with a mysql-container but it won't work

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, drupal

I started to learn Docker and wanted to connect a drupal-container with a mysql-database through docker-compose. It runs (also in the same Network), but whenever I try to login the database-variables in the drupal-browser-window, it doesn't find any connection to a database. Any Ideas?

**docker-compose-file:**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    db-drupal:
        image: mysql:latest
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
            - MYSQL_USER=user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
            - Mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
    drupal:
        image: drupal:latest
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - Drupal_modules:/var/www/html/modules
            - Drupal_profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
            - Drupal_sites:/var/www/html/sites
            - Drupal_themes:/var/www/html/themes
        depends_on:
            - db-drupal
        links:
            - db-drupal
        restart: always
    
volumes:
    Drupal_modules:
    Drupal_profiles:
    Drupal_sites:
    Drupal_themes:
    Mysql:
```

[here is the error that shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcbZq.png)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you edited settings.php to use the docker mysql host?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the text of the error, rather than an image file?  The question title suggests some sort of problem with database connectivity, can you also include whatever details of the database connection you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your example docker-compose file works, according to the instructions from the [official Drupal image](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal) with MySQL as database, I've tested it and it works fine if you put `db-drupal` as the database host (and not localhost).